# Ajax não retorna callback no IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ios

Estou com o seguinte problema, quando eu tento executar o meu código ele chegar no beforeSend porém ele não me retorna se aconteceu um erro ou foi executado com sucesso, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso. No PC e no Android ele funciona normalmente e faz o redirecionamento e até mostra o erro quando acontece.

```
event.preventDefault();

var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

//$("#stepTwoForm button[type=submit]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#alertError').hide();

clearColorFields();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/app/cadastro/passo3-store",
    async: true,
    cache:false,
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(){
        alert('enviou');
    },success: function (data) {
        if (data.url) {
            window.location.href = data.url
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        $("#stepTwoForm button[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.loader').css('visibility', 'hidden').css('opacity', '0');
        $('#stepTwoForm button[type=submit]').css('visibility', 'visible').css('opacity', '1').css('height', '40px');
        $('#alertError').html(data.responseJSON.messages);
        $('#alertError').show();
        alertRequests('error', data.responseJSON.messages, 'alertStoreProvider');
        colorRequiredFields(data.responseJSON.fields);
    }
});
```

Comment: "async: true,".. Ajax já é async

Comment: Cara, testei no iOS e funcionou como uma uva.